# Поиск слов в тексте

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые посетители hashcode.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, насчёт js.
Нужно проверить, есть ли в тексте `fmessage` "http://" и вернуть true или false.
Т.е. если `fmessage = "http://site.ru/123.txt";`, он должен вернуть true, а если `fmessage = "site.ru"`, то false. Искал в интернете, да там всё немного не то.

Comment: Рекомендую почитать про объект String и его методы
http://javascript.ru/String

Comment: А готовой функции нету? Я читал там всё запутанно жутко

Answer (score 2):

Метод `search()` ищет первое вхождение подстроки или наличие совпадений с регекспом.

```js
var fmessage = 'http://site.ru/123.txt';
if( fmessage.search('http://') != -1 )
  alert('Я нашел "http://"!');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'Т.е. если fmessage = "http://site.ru/123.txt";, он должен вернуть true';
var re = /(http:\/\/)+/i;
alert(re.test(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем тут использовать регулярки?

```
console.log("http://site.ru/123.txt".indexOf("http://") >= 0) 
// если есть вхождение подстроки, то вернет начальную позицию, 
// если нет то -1, от сюда и пляшем
// в нашем случае вернет true, если есть; false, если нет
```